# How decorators are passing its meta information to component classes in angular 2+?

Tags: angular, decorator, angular2-decorators

We are declaring component decorators above the class names in angular components. How it is identifying the particular decorators for that particular component classes ? what is the code logic behind this ?

Comment: You can find info on typescript docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html

Comment: but, i want to know how components and decorators are interconnected ? on what basis ?

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got what you want to know. Maybe this article can help you: https://blog.angularindepth.com/implementing-custom-component-decorator-in-angular-4d037d5a3f0d

Comment: yes it is useful. i understood  Angular uses wrapper function approach to decorators.thanks